# SQL JSON show one value of a string

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Lets say i have 3 columns in my Table. (Postgres Database)

Name, FirstName, Communication

My Communication column is a string with this text.

```
[{"typ":1,"kontext":1,"adresse":"031 *** ** **"},
 {"typ":2,"kontext":2,"adresse":"031 *** ** **"},
 {"typ":1,"kontext":2,"adresse":"+4179*******"}]
```

Now i want to make a query with Name,Firstname and Mobilenumber

How can i catch the number inside the string where the typ = 1 and kontext = 2 and make it a new column?

Comment: any database in particular ?

Comment: Hello @user2210516, Can you clarify your question? First you speak of name, firstname and communication as columns of your table. But in the next part of the question you have other properties in you json. Please edit your question more specificly

Comment: This is not really suitable for SQL. You might want to consider a redesign such that the database fits at least NF1 (no different information packed into the same column).

Comment: @RonaldHaan Sorry if i was unclear. The json is inside the Communication Column. And i only want mobilephone number from that string inside and make a new select with the mobile number instead of the Communication column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON path expression:

```
select name, firstname, 
       jsonb_path_query_first(communication, '$[*] ? (@."typ"==1 && @.kontext == 2).adresse') #> '{}' as mobile_number
from the_table
```

This assumes that `communication` is defined as a `jsonb` column (which it really should be). If it's not, you need to cast it `communication::jsonb`. It picks the first array elements where typ equals 1 and kontext equals 2.

`jsonb_path_query_first` returns a `jsonb` value and the expression `#> '{}'` turns that into a `text` value.